# how to optimize SQL query on Date field

Tags: sql, datetime

hi all i have a big large amount of data and i want to execute SQL  query for fetching data from server .Its take to much time to retrieving the data .Please suggest me how to otimize this query. here is my code :

```
SELECT count(*) as count,
       DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%b-%y') as dateName 
from myTable 
where date BETWEEN UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
and id=123 
GROUP BY DAY(date) 
order by date ASC
```

Comment: this query takes 50- 60 seconds for giving data.I want to optimize minimum time.

Comment: Can you try passing the actual dates instead of calling UTC_TIMESTAMP() for each record? Try using a hardcoded date first and see if performance improves. I believe you have a large dataset in there.

Comment: thanks for response but when i passed the actual dates its also take same time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) as count,
       DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%b-%y') as dateName 
from myTable, (select UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 30 DAY as start_date, UTC_TIMESTAMP() as end_date) dd  
where date BETWEEN dd.start_date AND dd.end_date
and id=123 
GROUP BY DAY(date) 
order by date ASC;
```

Try to define the dates as fields of a separate subquery in FROM to avoid calculations for each record

Comment: thanks for reply but its also take 58 second for retrieving data from server.

Comment: Try to add index for the 'date' column

Comment: sorry i don't know how to index for date column.

Comment: ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD INDEX (COLUMN_NAME);

Comment: i think GROUP BY DAY(date) takes too much time

Comment: Try also replace the ORDER BY  with order by DAY(date) ASC;

Comment: its fetch only one row

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49461/discussion-between-naresh-and-stanislavl)